# flutter how to load a List of type StreamBuilder efficiently

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function in which I add `StreamBuilder`(s) into a List, then I load these `StreamBuilder`(s) inside a `Column`, this approach is really memory consuming as all of the `List` is loaded at once, is there a way to do this in another way?

My `showList` function:

```
showList() {
    List<Widget> theList= [];
    for (CountryModel country in _allCountries) {
      theList.add(StreamBuilder(
      stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(country.Id).snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              xModel user = UserModel.fromDoc(snapshot.data);
              return CountryWidget(
                  country: country,
                  viewer: user.id as String,);
            } else {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          }));
    }
    return theList;
  }
```

In my Scaffold I have a Column where I use the spread operator to load a list into children[].

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ...showList()
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _allCountries.length + _anotherList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index >= _allCountries != true) {
      final CountryModel country = _allCountries[index];
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(country.Id).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            xModel user = UserModel.fromDoc(snapshot.data);
            return CountryWidget(
              country: country,
              viewer: user.id as String,
            );
          } else {
            return SizedBox.shrink();
          }
        }
        final item = _anotherList[index];
        return widget;
      },
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: Perfect. Now let's say I have two different types of widgets, a countryWidget and another, each with different parameters. is there a way to have them both in the same listview.builder? the reason I used the spread operator in the first place is because I have no Idea on how to go about this idea. is it also possible to have two different streams and to return the correct widget for each stream? also, is there a way to use orderBy on both of them simultaneously? they both have a shared field but in two different collections on firebase, is there a way to achieve all of this?

Comment: @andwaojd has a way. I will edit my answer